# I created a tab to give users two options for payments, but both options appear when I open up modal

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

I created a tab inside of a modal to give users the option of paying with their credit/debit card or using their checking/savings account.  It works fine. I can change from one option to the other. However,  when the modal opens up, both forms for credit/debit option and the checking/savings option appear together.  I would like for it to just show the credit/debit card option upon opening, and if the user wants to select the checking/savings option, they can then click on the tab. Can somebody help?

```html
    <div class="tab">
         <button class="tablinks" onclick="openOption(event, 'Card')">Credit/Debit</button>
         <button class="tablinks" onclick="openOption(event, 'Banking')">Banking</button>
     </div>
     <div id="Card" class="tabcontent">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-12">
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="cardNumber">CARD NUMBER</label>
                     <div class="input-group">
                         <input type="tel"
                                class="form-control"
                                name="cardNumber"
                                placeholder="Valid Card Number"
                                autocomplete="cc-number"
                                required autofocus
                                id="cardNumber" />
                         <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i></span>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-7">
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="cardExpiry"><span class="hidden-xs">EXPIRATION</span><span class="visible-xs-inline">EXP</span> DATE</label>
                     <input type="tel"
                            class="form-control"
                            name="cardExpiry"
                            placeholder="12 / 2016"
                            autocomplete="cc-exp"
                            required autofocus
                            id="expYear" />
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-5 pull-right">
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="cardCVC">CVC</label>
                     <input type="tel"
                            class="form-control"
                            name="cardCVC"
                            placeholder="CVC"
                            autocomplete="cc-csc"
                            required
                            id="cvc" />
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>

         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-12">
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="couponCode">NAME ON CARD</label>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="couponCode" id="name" />
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-12">
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="couponCode">STREET ADDRESS</label>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="couponCode" id="streetAddress" />
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-7">
                 <div>
                     <label for="couponCode">COUNTRY</label>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="COUNTY" value="US" readonly />
                 </div>
             </div>

             <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-5 pull-right">
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="couponCode">CITY</label>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CITY" id="city" />
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>

         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-7">
                 <div>
                     <label for="couponCode">REGION</label>
                     <div class="form-group">
                         <div class="col-xs-7">
                             <select class="form-control" id="state" name="state">
                                 <option value="" selected>N/A</option>
                                 <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                                 <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                                 <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                                 <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                                 <option value="CA">California</option>
                                 <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                                 <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                                 <option value="DC">District of Columbia</option>
                                 <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                                 <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                                 <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                                 <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                                 <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                                 <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                                 <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                                 <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                                 <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                                 <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                                 <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                                 <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                                 <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                                 <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                                 <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                                 <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                                 <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                                 <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                                 <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                                 <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                                 <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                                 <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                                 <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                                 <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                                 <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                                 <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                                 <option value="NY">New York</option>
                                 <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                                 <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                                 <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                                 <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                                 <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
                                 <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                                 <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                                 <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                                 <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                                 <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                                 <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                                 <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                                 <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                                 <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                                 <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                                 <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                                 <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                             </select>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>

             <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-5 pull-right">
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="couponCode">POSTAL CODE</label>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="couponCode" id="postalCode" />
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>

         <br>
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-12">
                 <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" id="createtoken" type="submit">Save</button>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div id="Banking" class="tabcontent">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-12">
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="accountType">Account Type</label>
                     <select id="accountType">
                         <option value="">Please select an account</option>
                         <option value="checking">Checking</option>
                         <option value="savings">Savings</option>
                     </select>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="routeNumber"><span class="hidden-xs">ROUTING NUMBER</span></label>
                     <input type="tel"
                            class="form-control"
                            name="routeNumber"
                            placeholder="111111111111" />
                 </div>
             </div>
             @*<div class="col-xs-5 col-md-5 pull-right">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cardCVC">CVC</label>
                    <input type="tel"
                           class="form-control"
                           name="cardCVC"
                           placeholder="CVC"
                           autocomplete="cc-csc"
                           required
                           id="cvc" />
                </div>
            </div>*@
         </div>

         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                 <div>
                     <label for="accountNumber">ACCOUNT NUMBER</label>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ACCOUNTNUMBER" value="ACCOUNT NUMBER" readonly />
                 </div>
             </div>

             <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="confirmAccount">CONFIRM ACCOUNT NUMBER</label>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CONFIRMACCOUNT" id="confirmAccount" value="CONFIRM ACCOUNT NUMBER" />
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="holdersName"><span class="hidden-xs">ACCOUNT HOLDERS NAME</span></label>
                     <input type="tel"
                            class="form-control"
                            name="holdersName"
                            placeholder="YOUR NAME" />
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         <br>
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-12">
                 <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" id="createtoken" type="submit">Save</button>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     
     <script>
          function openOption(evt, optionName) {
            var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
                tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
                for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
                tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
            for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            document.getElementById(optionName).style.display = "block";
            evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
            }

     </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="Banking" class="tabcontent" hidden>
```

This should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

```
display:none
```

Add this css for both the links if you want both of them to be hidden by default or add to one of them if you want the other to be visible by default.